# How can we display the dynamic kml files data with in the Arcgis online maps

Tags: google-maps, arcgis, arcgis-js-api

Hi I have developed a website using **google maps**.My map will display the **markers** based on the kml files data which is on my server.Now I want to change the maps to **Arcgis Online** .Can I display the same kml files data with the **Arcgis online maps** ?
My kml files data will be changed accordingly.The total website is depends upon the kml files.

please suggest me whether I can change from **google maps** to **Arcgis online.**

Note:I dont have much idea on java and .net so Can I make an attempt to Arcgis online maps

Answer (score 0):

As long as your KML is accessible to the web application user, you can display it using the ArcGIS API for JavaScript. Use the [`KMLLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/kmllayer-amd.html) class. Note that this class requires a connection to ArcGIS Online, which converts the KML.

Comment: Thanks For your answer Yes I found ArcGIS Api is useful.But why this KML layer class requires Arcgis Online Connection .In the example https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_kml.html they didn't use any ArcGIS online connection

Comment: That example actually does use ArcGIS Online. If you run it with the Chrome developer tools or with Fiddler, you'll see a request to `utility.arcgis.com` . I think you can point this to your own Portal for ArcGIS if desired. The ArcGIS component that reads and converts KML is part of ArcGIS Online and Portal for ArcGIS. The ArcGIS API for JavaScript doesn't do the conversion client-side at this time.